# How to use multicore python with PyQt4 process?

Tags: python, pyqt4, multiprocessing, signals-slots

I am writing an app in pyqt4 that has to read in and parse a lot of xml files. Done single-threaded it takes a while to do all that parsing and make the thousands of python objects corresponding to that incoming xml. I have profiled the code and as far as I can tell it's compute, not I/O, bound.

I would like to convert the app to a multi-core model to spread the load around, using a worker-farm model (?Process.Pool in python).

However, I would also like to be able to Signal progress from the workers to update the gui.

It seems to me from what I have read so far that QThread is not multicore capable (because it round-robins on one core) but I need QThread to do Signal, and so essentially I can't do that.

I might be able to arrange not to need to Signal from a worker, only from the farmer, which might then mean I can carry on, but then I wonder: can I return a list of python objects from one Process to another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Spawn a QThread.
- The QThread can farm out tasks to the multiprocessing Pool. You might
  use [pool.apply_async()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) which has a callback parameter.
- The callback parameter allows you to specify a function which is
  called when the target function completes.
- The callback runs in the QThread, and is sent the return value of the
  target function as its one and only argument.
- Each time the callback function runs, you can update the GUI to
  indicate the progress.

Comment: Thank you for this. It is roughly what I wondered about with my "arrange not to need" para, though good to know it could work. Will multiprocessing return my python objects though?

Comment: The multiprocessing pool communicates with subprocesses by way of [Queues](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue). Everything transfered through the Queue is pickled. So the value returned by the target function must be picklable. Here is a list of the types of [things that can be pickled](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). Note that it is also possible to teach Python [how to pickle new types of objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types).

Comment: So the short answer is, as long as the return value is picklable, everything is a-okay.

Comment: Is there any example of this?