# How to implement multicore processing in Python 3 and PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, multicore, pyqt5, python-multiprocessing

**Background:** I am trying to implement multicore processing in a python 3.4 `PyQT5` application.

In the application I have `numpy.ndarrays` of frames, imagine it like a `[n,m,t]` array. I need to process each `[n,m,:]` array and using multicore would linearly speed up my process.

I've played with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and got a simple script together using part of example scripts and gave me the following idea:

**Simple No GUI code**:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy

aa = numpy.random.rand(4,2,3)

def random_function(x):
    return x,x**3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

    #with apply_asynch

    #results = [pool.apply_async(cube, args=(aa[:,:,x],)) for x in range(0,aa.shape[2])]
    #output = [p.get() for p in results]
    #test_va = numpy.asarray( output)


    #with apply

    results = [pool.apply(random_function, args=(aa[:,:,x],)) for x in range(0,aa.shape[2])]
    test_va = numpy.asarray( results)
```

This works and does about what I need it to do.

**Issue:** Now when I implement this in `PyQT5` I incur in the "pickling" problem . So following suggestions for `PyQT4` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410416/how-to-use-multicore-python-with-pyqt4-process) I've made a simple GUI, spawn a thread and use multiprocessing. As a result I've got the same GUI replicated 4 times and it just does not seem to work.

**PyQT5 GUI non working code:**

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy

class WorkThread(QThread):
    finished = pyqtSignal(int,object)


    def __del__(self):
      self.wait()

    def cube(x):
        return x,x**3

    def run(self):
        aa = numpy.random.rand(4,2,3)

        pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
        results = [pool.apply_async(self.cube, args=(aa[:,:,x],)) for x in range(0,aa.shape[2])]
        output = [p.get() for p in results]
        test_va = numpy.asarray( output)

        for i in range(5):

            QThread.sleep(0.3) # artificial time delay

            self.finished.emit(i,test_va)




class test_multicore(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Qthreads and multicore')

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.testButton = QPushButton("test")
        self.testButton.clicked.connect(self.test)

        self.listwidget = QListWidget(self)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.testButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)
        self.threadPool = []

    def add(self, text,random_matrix): 
        """ Add item to list widget """
        print ("Add: " + str(text) +str(random_matrix))
        self.listwidget.addItem(str(text))
        self.listwidget.sortItems()

    def addBatch(self,text="text",iters=6,delay=0.3): 
        """ Add several items to list widget """
        for i in range(iters):
            time.sleep(delay) # artificial time delay
            self.add(text+" "+str(i), 0)


    def test(self):
        self.listwidget.clear()

        self.addBatch("_non_thread_entries",iters=6,delay=0.3)




        self.workThread = WorkThread()
        self.workThread.finished[int,object].connect(self.add)


        self.workThread.start()






# run
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
test = test_multicore()
test.show()
app.exec_()
```

I've also tried using `Qobject` and passing it to a thread with `moveToThread` but got the same issue again.

**Question:** 
How do I implement multicore processing in my Python 3.4 `PyQT5` application? Consider that I will deploy using `cx_freeze` on Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

before environment creation ensures the app is created once.

This is a working code/example for Multiprocessing pyqt5 python 3.4.

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy

class WorkThread(QThread):
    finished = pyqtSignal(int,object)


    def __del__(self):
      self.wait()

    def cube(self,x):
        return x,x**3

    def run(self):
        aa = numpy.random.rand(4,2,3)

        pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
        results = [pool.apply_async(self.cube, args=(aa[:,:,x],)) for x in range(0,aa.shape[2])]
        output = [p.get() for p in results]
        test_va = numpy.asarray( output)

        for i in range(5):

            QThread.sleep(0.3) # artificial time delay

            self.finished.emit(i,test_va)




class test_multicore(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Qthreads and multicore')

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.testButton = QPushButton("test")
        self.testButton.clicked.connect(self.test)

        self.listwidget = QListWidget(self)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.testButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)
        self.threadPool = []

    def add(self, text,random_matrix): 
        """ Add item to list widget """
        print ("Add: " + str(text) +str(random_matrix))
        self.listwidget.addItem(str(text))
        self.listwidget.sortItems()

    def addBatch(self,text="text",iters=6,delay=0.3): 
        """ Add several items to list widget """
        for i in range(iters):
            time.sleep(delay) # artificial time delay
            self.add(text+" "+str(i), 0)


    def test(self):
        self.listwidget.clear()

        self.addBatch("_non_thread_entries",iters=6,delay=0.3)




        self.workThread = WorkThread()
        self.workThread.finished[int,object].connect(self.add)


        self.workThread.start()






# run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = test_multicore()
    test.show()
    app.exec_()
```

To use apply_asynch substitute:

```
results = [pool.apply_async(cube, args=(aa[:,:,x],)) for x in range(0,aa.shape[2])]
output = [p.get() for p in results]
test_va = numpy.asarray( output)
```

Comment: This is not working due to the pickling that takes place to transfer data between processes. Specifically, pickling is not possible for generators objects such as p.get() in the output variable. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Not working indeed: `TypeError: cannot pickle 'WorkThread' object`

Comment: Got a "TypeError: cannot pickle 'WorkThread' object" error as well.

Answer (score 1):

Now I was trying to figure out how to launch multiple windows within their own umbrella (which is kind of what this question is asking) and the first thing I found out was that one cannot use a QWidget (or any Widget for that matter) within a sub-thread (a question that erroneously got dubbed a duplicate) as they must only reside within the main thread (at least I got a correct answer). Okay so then the question became can I create more than one main thread well I find out that I can do that using Multi-processing but that was not that simple since all the examples I could find did not show how this could be done. So in case anyone else might be struggling with this I thought I would post my basic implementation of this in order to give you a potential path should you wish to implement something like this yourself.

Further it gives a potential answer to this question.  Now specifically this example shows not only how to launch two windows in different processes but these two windows also contain a secondary thread -- so a sort of multi-answer for multi-processing.

```
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing as mlti

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class WorkerGUI(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, InFunc):
        super(WorkerGUI, self).__init__()
        self.Func = InFunc

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.Func()

class ChildWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.Name = name
        print('Name :',name)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.Name)
        if name == 'One':
            self.setGeometry(100,100,250,100)
        else:
            self.setGeometry(100,500,250,100)
        self.CountThis = False
        self.StartThis = True
        self.RunThis   = True

        self.btnCnt = QPushButton('Cnt')
        self.btnCnt.clicked.connect(self.CountMe)

        self.lblCntr = QLabel()
        self.lblCntr.setText('0')

        HBox = QHBoxLayout()
        HBox.addWidget(self.btnCnt)
        HBox.addWidget(QLabel('     '))
        HBox.addWidget(self.lblCntr)
        HBox.addStretch(1)

        VBox = QVBoxLayout()
        VBox.addLayout(HBox)
        VBox.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(VBox)
        self.WrkrGUI = WorkerGUI(self.CountOnMe)

    def CountMe(self):
        if self.CountThis:
            self.btnCnt.setText('Cnt')
            self.CountThis = False
        else:
            self.btnCnt.setText('Off')
            self.CountThis = True
            if self.StartThis:
                self.StartThis = False
                self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
                self.threadpool.start(self.WrkrGUI)

    def CountOnMe(self):
        cnt = 0
        while self.RunThis:
            while self.CountThis:
                cnt += 1
                self.lblCntr.setText(str(cnt))
                time.sleep(.01)
            time.sleep(.01)

def Process2():
    MainThred = QApplication([])

    ChildGUI = ChildWindow('Two')
    ChildGUI.show()

    sys.exit(MainThred.exec_())

def Process1():
    MainThred = QApplication([])

    ChildGUI = ChildWindow('One')
    ChildGUI.show()

    sys.exit(MainThred.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprcess1 = mlti.Process(target=Process1)
    multiprcess2 = mlti.Process(target=Process2)

    multiprcess1.start()
    multiprcess2.start()
```