# How can I use QThread to create a Multi-Core PyQt application?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, bigdata, qthread

I've run into a little problem while working on a "realtime" Big Data Python PyQt application.
I've set up 3 QThreads, that use Signal-Slot to communicate with the GUI:
The first one obviously is the GUI main thread.
The second thread keeps my database updated, every 0.3s.
And the third one uses the database to perform calculations using pandas, it takes around 3 secondas.

It all works except that the UI performance is somewhat sluggish because the Third thread is really CPU intensive (takes ~3 seconds to complete each cycle using 100% of the CPU power).

So, to overcome this, I'm thinking about using a multicore aproach, but can seem to find a way to do this, every resource says that Python is locked, unless I use the multithreading lib, but, from what I understand, it is not compatible with QThread.

So the question is how can I use QThread to create a multicore capable PyQt application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multicore python with PyQt4 process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410416/how-to-use-multicore-python-with-pyqt4-process)

Comment: Maybe, I'll this solution... Thanks